# Rematch for Redux: Setting State to that of the Payload when Signing Up

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, react-redux, rematch

How do I **set state** to that of my payload? I would like my **global state** to have the **recent changes**, **not** the **payload**. Please could someone explain **why/how** this is happening? Do I need to create another reducer/effect to set the state? I want to set this state as global within the app. I would greatly appreciate it.

I am using the following:

- Firebase **Firestore**
- **Rematch** for Redux
- **React Native**

This is [My debugger (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYrZX.png).

[Result of the code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwJIl.jpg).

Here is my **code**:

**Index.js**

```
import { init } from '@rematch/core'
import user from './user'

const models = {
    user,
}

const store = init({
    models,
})

export default { getState, dispatch } = store
```

**Model.js (User.js)**

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import db from '../config/firebase'

const user = {
    state: {},
    reducers: {
        login(userData) {
            return userData
        },
        email(state, email) {
            return { ...state, email }
        },
        password(state, password) {
            return { ...state, password }
        },
        username(state, username) {
            return { ...state, username }
        },
        fullname(state, fullname) {
            return { ...state, fullname }
        },
    },
    effects: () => ({
        async signup() {
            const { email, password, username, fullname } = getState().user
            const response = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            if (response.user.uid) {
                const userData = {
                    uid: response.user.uid,
                    email: email,
                    username: username,
                    fullname: fullname,
                    bio: 'test',
                    gender: 'teste',
                    phoneNum: 'teste',
                    profilePic: 'te',
                    status: 'teste',
                }

                db.collection('users').doc(response.user.uid).set(userData)
                alert(userData.uid)
                return dispatch.user.login(userData)
            }
        }
    })
}

export default user
```

**SignUp.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
    TextInput,
    Text,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    SafeAreaView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Alert,
}
    from 'react-native';
import styles from '../styles'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import '@expo/vector-icons';
import 'redux';

class Signup extends React.Component {

    onPress = () => {
        this.props.SignUp()
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
    }

    render() {
        const { routeName } = this.props.navigation.state
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='position'>
                    <Text style={styles.mainText}>
                        EMAIL
                    </Text>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputText}
                        editable={routeName === 'Signup' ? true : false}
                        value={this.props.user.email}
                        onChangeText={input => this.props.setEmail(input)}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.mainText}>
                        PASSWORD
                    </Text>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputText}
                        editable={routeName === 'Signup' ? true : false}
                        value={this.props.user.password}
                        onChangeText={input => this.props.setPassword(input)}
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.mainText}>
                        USERNAME
                    </Text>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputText}
                        value={this.props.user.username}
                        onChangeText={input => this.props.setUserName(input)}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.mainText}>
                        FULL NAME
                    </Text>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputText}
                        value={this.props.user.fullname}
                        onChangeText={input => this.props.setFullName(input)}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.buttonLighGray}
                        onPress={() => this.onPress()}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonDarkText}>
                            Accept & Sign Up
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}

const mapState = (state) => ({
    user: state.user,
})

const mapDispatch = (dispatch) => ({
    setEmail: mail => dispatch.user.email(mail),
    setPassword: pass => dispatch.user.password(pass),
    setUserName: usern => dispatch.user.username(usern),
    setFullName: fulln => dispatch.user.fullname(fulln),
    SignUp: () => dispatch.user.signup(),
})

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(Signup)
```

**Screen.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    TextInput,
    Alert,
    Text,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    SafeAreaView,
    TouchableOpacity,
}
    from 'react-native';
import styles from '../styles'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Image } from 'react-native-elements';
import '@expo/vector-icons';
import 'redux';
import firebase from 'firebase' 

class Screen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                    <Text> Full Name: {this.props.user.fullName}</Text>
                    <Text> Email: {this.props.user.email}</Text>
                    <Text> username: {this.props.user.username}</Text>
                    <Text> bio: {this.props.user.bio}</Text>
                    <Text> gender: {this.props.user.gender}</Text>
                    <Text> phoneNum: {this.props.user.phoneNum}</Text>
                    <Text> profilePic: {this.props.user.profilePic}</Text>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}

const mapState = (state) => ({
    user: state.user,
})

const mapDispatch = (dispatch) => ({
    setEmail: mail => dispatch.user.email(mail),
    setPassword: pass => dispatch.user.password(pass),
    setUserName: usern => dispatch.user.username(usern),
    setFullName: fulln => dispatch.user.fullname(fulln),
})

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(Screen)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning the current **state** again in the login reducer. (you declared is at user data)

```js
login(state, payload) {
  return {
   ...state,
   ...payload
  }
  // this will take the global state and overwrite everything that is in payload (merge both objects
},
```

else you could just do just `return payload` but this could overwrite other stored values in the future!